# For incredibly large N value which is asymptotical worst time complexity?

Tags: time-complexity

For a very large n value which is asymptotical worst or upper bound?

`N!` or `N^googol`

```
1 googol = 1.0 × 10^100
```

Answer (score 0):

`N!` grows asymptotically faster than any polynomial. It doesn't matter how large an exponent you can come up with.